# IPython notebook kernel failed

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ipython

When I launch the ipython notebook in MacOSX El Capitan (10.11) and try to open an existing notebook, I get the following error when the kernel has been initiated:

```
[I 15:22:08.733 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 8e77535e-2af7-462d-9091-da5686de9a36
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/localinterfaces.py:242: UserWarning: Unexpected error discovering local network interfaces: insecure string pickle
  warn("Unexpected error discovering local network interfaces: %s" % e)
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Invalid Message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 175, in dispatch_shell
    msg = self.session.deserialize(msg, content=True, copy=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 870, in deserialize
    return adapt(message)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/adapter.py", line 386, in adapt
    header['date'] = datetime.now().isoformat()
NameError: global name 'datetime' is not defined
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Invalid Message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 175, in dispatch_shell
    msg = self.session.deserialize(msg, content=True, copy=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 870, in deserialize
    return adapt(message)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/adapter.py", line 386, in adapt
    header['date'] = datetime.now().isoformat()
NameError: global name 'datetime' is not defined
```

The kernel then dies...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Has anything changed since the last time you used iPython notebook? Did you just upgrade your OS?

Comment: Also, what browser do you use to open a notebook?

Comment: Yes, I upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan. With both browsers, Safari and Firefox, I get the same problems. I have reinstalled IPython via pip and the problem remains. And it is something I cannot understand because I have also made the same steps in another computer and everything goes fine...

Comment: Finally, I solved it by reinstalling the jupyter-client package:

pip install jupyter-client --upgrade --force-reinstall